# trying to understand how to find a path to file using MacBook Mojave OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-mojave, eclipse-oxygen

i have a problem trying read a file on java with MacBook OS Mojave version- 10.14.1  with eclipse version Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

when i run this: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Macintosh HD/⁨Users⁩/Username⁩/Desktop/Java/Hi.txt⁩"));

when i run the code it appears: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ("/Macintosh HD/⁨Users⁩/Username⁩/Desktop/Java/⁩Hi.txt")
 (No such file or directory)

is there something another way to find the path to file or something that I'm missing writing the actual path to file?

I'm expecting the output to be a String "this is line 1"

Comment: Note what the absolute path for `Users` folder is...

Answer (score 1):

## Drag file from *Finder* to *Terminal* window

To determine the full path to file on your Mac:

1. Open Terminal.app.
2. Locate your file or folder in the Finder.
3. Drag the file or folder into the open Terminal window.

The full path is written into the Terminal. You may copy the text from there. Paste into your Java source code.

See the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) by Oracle.

[image: screenshot of dragging a file from Finder to Terminal]

Here is a complete example in a single `.java` file.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class FileReader {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        FileReader app = new FileReader();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        String pathText = "/Users/basilbourque/Desktop/Hi.txt";
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( pathText );
        try {
            Files.lines( path ).forEach( s -> System.out.println( s ) );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( "ERROR - IOException while reading the `Hi.text` file. Message # 8640b80f-49a1-4ee7-992c-c661ef4cf38e." );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> Bonjour
>
> Olá
>
> Hello
>
> Sawa
>
> Hei
>
> Halló
>
> こんにちは
>
> Salve

Comment: i have opened the terminal app and copied the code but it still can't find it. Ive yet to figure out why the account name is my username

Answer (score 0):

'Macintosh HD' is just a name Finder gives to the main disk, it isn't used as part of the file path. So your file path would be:

```
/Users⁩/Username⁩/Desktop/Java/⁩Hi.txt
```

This assumes your user name is 'Username' and the file is in a folder 'Java' in the 'Desktop' folder.